# Can spring boot project be built and developed without the Internet?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

Because the project is supposed to build and develop on a server that is not connected to the Internet, 
My question is whether I can use spring boot and gradle To build and develop a project with these conditions?
thanks.

Comment: Hi Reza, the only moment you need internet would be to build the project where gradle download the dependencies. Once built, you can run the JAR anywhere with no internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few situations you might need internet connection:

1. You need to download Gradle wrapper to build the app.

   - Download the Gradle and save it. ([Link](https://gradle.org/install/))
   - Address the Gradle to use offline mode and your own downloaded one.
     [image: Gradle]
2. You have some Gradle dependencies that are not cached yet.

   - You can download them as `JAR` files and add them to the `libs` directory and use `compile files('libs/library.jar')`
   - If you could connect, download them using the Gradle (uncheck Offline mode) and cache as many as you can.

Answer (score 0):

You need a source of dependencies for your project - if you want them to be locally they should be downloaded and somehow delivered to your hardware (external disc drive, USB, etc).

After all local dependencies are present, there's several options on how to use them via gradle:

1. Put lib to local drive (neither just somewhere on disc drive or put it to the project files) and use direct gradle jar linking - just putting relative path of dependency to your build file like this:

`dependencies {
  compile files('libs/something_local.jar')
}`

2. A bit complicated but could work if you need to be able easily switch to internet dependency source - setup local binary repository (nexus, jfrog artifactory, etc) and import dependencies from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can download all depending jars in your local repository and reference it locally.